# What causes this PFUbiquityLocationStatus error and how to fix?

Tags: ios, core-data, runtime-error

I have a core data app and after making a change on a second device, the original device reports the following error (right before making the change):

```
2014-04-10 18:00:27.119 My App[146:4a17] -[PFUbiquityLocationStatus checkFileURLState](159): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Error reading resource values for URL: file:///var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/MYAPPIDENTIFIERCONTAINER/CoreData/UserData/.baseline/UserData/rOA7ppxlvKj41IpKPMtDNKL7rtsjl00Z4TBbQ6Jxct0=/mobile~BAF9FD29-32AF-40FA-8BF6-2815E01A69DA
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260 - Request for item properties on non-existent item.)" UserInfo=0x17f6a320 {NSDescription=Request for item properties on non-existent item.}
```

The change made it, so it may be irrelevant, but having errors like this appear make me nervous about shipping this app.

Has anyone else had this error or know what causes it or how to fix it?

Comment: I'm getting the same error in the same situation. Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: As of now, I still do not have a resolution.  I posted this as a bug report as well, but have not heard back.  My guess is they'll say "wait for iOS 8"

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with one device (and not on the other). It seems that a local folder may have been corrupted. My solution was to delete the app, restart the device and reinstall the app.